# Accessing a containerized application from another application running on a local machine

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, containers, port, host

I have two applications that both run on the same host: main application that sends a REST API call to the second supporting application. To connect to the second application, we are using Spring framework and its WebClient. We are passing the URL containing the host for the second application and the endpoint to the WebClient. Currently, the host and port for the second application are configured to be localhost:port. This configuration works and we have no issues.

We have new requirements and now the supporting application has to be containerized. We created a simple container that runs the supporting application. The container is running on an AWS EC2 instance. It works and the application is running inside the container. To publish the port on the host, we are adding -p 0.0.0.0::.

In the main application, we are now changing the localhost:port configuration to the following: :port. The connection times out.

I thought the issue was security group configuration on EC2 and added an inbound rule that configured HTTP traffic on port 80 (default). I published the port on the container adding this: -p 0.0.0.0:**80**:. Still the same issue - connection times out.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Is it a networking issue where the incoming traffic is blocked by the EC2? Or am I configuring access to the containerized application incorrectly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `-p 80:80`.  Also make sure the supporting application is listening on 0.0.0.0 not 127.0.0.1 which is not shared by host / container.

Comment: Thank you. My supporting application is configured to run on port 8081 like so: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8081), so when I'm publishing the port, I'm adding -p 80:8081. So far this didn't work for me. I'm getting connection timeout.

Comment: If you are starting these containers using docker you have different network modes that will allow containers to see the network differently. Check the docker documentation for the different network modes and this might help. When I am testing stuff out I use hostmode for example which keeps things simple

Comment: So the issue was that my main application is running on an EC2 from a different amazon VPN than the supporting application EC2. When I attempted to connect from my local machine (not EC2), the connection to the container worked with no issues.

Comment: Why did you not use a service like ECS to run your Docker containers? AWS App Runner is another great alternative.